# Controlling ILI9341 LCD with STMF0

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, lcd

I am trying to control a ILI9341 LCD screen with a STM32F072RB Nucleo board using the parallel intel 8080 interface, but the only thing I accomplished is lighting the screen fully white when the LED power is applied.

I tried different ways of implementing the control, here is the last one (I based on the adafruit library for stm32uino, basically tried to port it https://github.com/stevstrong/Adafruit_TFTLCD_8bit_STM32/blob/master/examples/graphicstest/graphicstest.ino).

But as I said, nothing is happening. Here's the code (i deleted most of the CUBEMX comments so it's more readable):

```
#include "main.h"

int DISPLAY_ON = 41;
int PIXEL_FORMAT_CHANGE_COMMAND = 58;
int PIXEL_FORMAT_SIX_BIT = 230;
int SET_COLUMN_COMMAND = 42;
int SET_PAGE_COMMAND = 43;
int MEMORY_WRITE_COMMAND = 44;
int DCX_HIGH = 1;
int DCX_LOW = 0;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

void setDataBus(int);
void setColorScreen(void);
void setColumn(int, int); 
void setPage(int, int);
void setColorDepth(void);
void resetLCD(void);
void displayOn(void);
void setPixel(int, int, int, int, int);
void sendWrite(int, int);

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();


    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 1); // reset
    HAL_Delay(150);
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 40); // display off 
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 58); // pixel format
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 230); // pixel format data
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 17); // sleep out
    HAL_Delay(150);
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 41); // display on
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 54); // memory access control
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH,74); 

    MX_GPIO_Init();
    setColorScreen();

  while (1)
  {
  }

}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI48;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSI48State = RCC_HSI48_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI48;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13 
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA3 PA5 PA8 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_8;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB10 PB12 PB13 
                           PB14 PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13 
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC8 PC9 PC10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PD2 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

void setColorScreen(void){

    setColumn(0, 159);
    setPage(0, 127);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // csx low
    HAL_Delay(1);
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, 44);

    for(int i=0; i<128*160*3; i++)
    {
        sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 125);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); // csx low
    HAL_Delay(1);
}

void setColumn(int startColumn, int endColumn) 
{   
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // csx low
    HAL_Delay(1);
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, SET_COLUMN_COMMAND);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 0);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, startColumn);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 0);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, endColumn);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); // csx high
    HAL_Delay(1);

}

void setPage(int startPage, int endPage)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // csx low
    HAL_Delay(1);
    sendWrite(DCX_LOW, SET_PAGE_COMMAND);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 0);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, startPage);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, 0);
    sendWrite(DCX_HIGH, endPage);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET); // csx high
    HAL_Delay(1);

}

void setDataBus(int number)
{
    GPIO_TypeDef *dbPort[]  = {GPIOC, GPIOC , GPIOD, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB, GPIOB};
    uint16_t dbNumber[] = {GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_10};

    int shifted;

    for(int i = 7; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        shifted = number >> i;

        if(shifted & 1)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(dbPort[i%8], dbNumber[i%8], GPIO_PIN_SET);
        }   else 
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(dbPort[i%8], dbNumber[i%8], GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        }
    }
}


void sendWrite(int dcx, int data)
{

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, (dcx == 1) ? GPIO_PIN_SET : GPIO_PIN_RESET); // d/cx set
    HAL_Delay(1);

    setDataBus(data);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // wrx low
    HAL_Delay(1);

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET); // wrx high
    HAL_Delay(1);


}

void Error_Handler(void)
{

}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(char *file, uint32_t line)
{ 

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: I believe that your initialization sequence is not enough.

Comment: what is missing?

Comment: A lots of stuff. Take any example code and see the difference

Comment: BTW i think ,you on it the gpio after you use them

Comment: Perhaps you should try running the stm32uino version first to validate the wiring...